# Change Record View in page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, razor

I have model like

```
public class Test
{
    public string PatientName{get; set;}
    public string Address{get; set;}
    public string TestName{get; set;}
}
```

In my table, i have

```
TestID  PatientName   Address  TestName
1       yyy           xxxxx    Test1
2       yyy           xxxxx    Test2
3       zzz           aaaaa    Test1
4       zzz           aaaaa    Test2
5       zzz           aaaaa    Test3
```

where a patient can have many test.
But in my show page i like to show it as

```
Patient Name        Address             Test Name
yyy                 xxxxx               Test1, Test2
zzz                 aaaaa               Test1, Test2, Test3
```

i can't do a query to show like in the above.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy`:

```
var tests = db.Tests.GroupBy(m => new { m.PatientName, m.Address });
```

Then, in your view, you would just do:

```
@foreach (var patient in tests)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@patient.Key.PatientName</td>
        <td>@patient.Key.Address</td>
        <td>@String.Join(", ", patient.Select(m => m.TestName))</td>
    </tr>
}
```